# Problem with assigning a value to nested dictionary in VBA

Tags: vba, data-structures

I have an issue with assigning a value to a nested dictionary in VBA.
The structure is dict(strValue)(dateValue)(arrayIndex).

where dict is dictionary, strValue is key of dictionary, dateValue is key of nested dictionary and the nested dictionary value is an array.

The data structure is properly declared and the inner members are successfully assigned. I have only problem with assigning the most inner value(the array members).

What I have tried is:

```
dict(outD & " - " & inD)(dt)(h) = "str"
```

After the assignment the expected value in the dictionary is empty string and should not be.

Comment: Have you broken it down into sections to make sure, like `d=dict(outd & " - " & inD)` see if a dictionary object is returned etc.  Also look in the locals window to see your structure.

Comment: Are you aware that `str` is a build in function in VBA?

Comment: @FunThomas it is actually a string value, the most inner array is array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any documentation about this, but I did some test and I would assume you are out of luck here.

An array is not an object in VBA, so if you put an array as a value into a dictionary-entry, VBA will *copy* all it's values. See for example:

```
a(1) = "A-1"
dict.Add "MyA", a
a(2) = "A-2"
Debug.Print dict("MyA")(1), dict("MyA")(2)    ' Will print "A-1" (but not "A-2")
```

Now, if you change your code to

```
a(1) = "A-1"
dict.Add "MyA", a
dict("MyA")(2) = "A-2"
Debug.Print dict("MyA")(1), dict("MyA")(2)    ' Will still print "A-1" (but not "A-2")
```

Why?

It's just a guess: When you access `dict("MyA")`, VBA copies the *value*. As this *value* is an array, it will copy the array (into memory). You then modify the 2nd member of the *copy*, but this will not change the array that is stored in the dictionary.

A workaround could be using a `Collection` rather than an array.

Comment: Note: a `Collection` won't let you swap its values either; you need to remove and re-add an item to replace it.